# Is the minmod limiter energy stable?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, hyperbolic-pde, numerical-analysis-of-pde

It is well-known, that upwind scheme and Lax-Wendroff scheme are energy stable for the linear advection equation $u_t +a u_x = 0$ with periodic boundary conditions, if the CFL condition is satisfied, that is the schemes never raise the L2-norm.
In formulae: Given a state $u(t)=(u_{i,t})_{i \in I}$ at timestep $t \in \mathbb{N}$, we have
$$ \lVert u(t) \rVert_2^2 = \sum_{i \in I} u_{i,t}^2 \geq \sum_{i \in I} u_{i,t+1}^2 = \lVert u(t+1) \rVert_2^2 $$

Is the minmod-limiter also energy-stable and if so, can you point me to a paper?
Numerical experiments suggest unequivocally that this is the case but I know of no proof.
The only relevant article I found, is [this one](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3c38/516fd61bbe1983eaaf705351c04b02ca536a.pdf),<sup>1</sup> which only deals with differences in L2-norm. Theorem 4.1 therein can be used to conclude that the L2-norm of a numerical solution is not too far away from the L2-norm of the exact solution, but not that it is smaller or equal.

<sup>1</sup>Sergei Konyagin, Bojan Popov, and Ognian Trifonov: *On Convergence of Minmod-Type Schemes,* SIAM J. Numer. Anal., 42(5), 1978–1997. https://doi.org/10.1137/S0036142903423861

Answer (score 1):

As so often in math, this is an old result, were you just have to happen accross the right keywords to google, see the paper below.

The essence is this: For every conservation law with an entropy-entropy-flux pair there is a (unstable) numerical scheme, let's call it "C", that conserves the corresponding numerical entropy.
If you find another scheme, whose numerical viscosity is pointwise greater or equal to the numerical viscosity of C, then this new scheme is entropy stable.

Luckily the advection equation has the L2-norm squared as an entropy and the corresponding C-scheme has vanishing numerical viscosity.
Therefore any scheme with non-negative numerical viscosity is L2-stable for the advection equation, hence also the minmod-limited scheme.

[E. Tadmor, 1987](https://home.cscamm.umd.edu/people/faculty/tadmor/pub/TV+entropy/Tadmor.MathComp1987.pdf)
The numerical viscosity of entropy stable schemes for systems of conservation laws. I.
Mathematics of Computation 49 (1987), 91-103.